# Changing the font size of a specific piece of text - Python/Pygame

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I am trying to figure out how to change the font size of a specific line of text in my Pygame program.

I have used this:

```
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
```

To change the size to 40, however this changes all font sizes on the screen to 40, I want to be able to independently change the font sizes.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create many fonts

```
 font_20 = pygame.font.Font(None, 20) 
 font_40 = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
```

and then use different font with different text.

```
 text1 = font_20.render("Hello", ...)
 text2 = font_40.render("World", ...)
```